# Opshub Migration from TFS to VSTS not mapping users

Tags: opshub, azure-devops

So I've been trying to perform a migration (code only, no work items) of a medium sized project from an on-premises TFS2010 to VSTS using the OpsHub tool.  My user is an administrator on both sides, and the migration runs and completes without tossing errors.

The problem is that it just doesn't do what it says it will.  I spent a long time mapping the users from TFS to VSTS during the setup, but it completely ignored that mapping and assigned every single changeset to my VSTS account.  The docs also say that it should preserve the original TFS check-in time in the comment of the new VSTS changeset, but it never does that to any of them -- the comments are just brought over exactly as they were.

It seems like there must be a setting set wrong in OpsHub to turn these features on, but I can't find any kind of options screen or anything in the tool.  It looks like other users are able to successfully map the TFS users to the VSTS users and have it work like you would expect, but I can't make heads or tails of it.

Thanks for any help or advice on this.

Comment: Which edition are you using? Free or Commercial?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the free version then this feature is not supported by it and same is mention on the visual studio gallery download page, only the commercial version of migration utility supports partial user impersonation, i.e. writing changes as per configured user mapping.

Comment: I have questions then:
1 -- Why does the free utility even force user mapping if it isn't used for anything?
2 -- Why do all the Microsoft references to this tool contradict this?  The migration guide on the visual studio site clearly shows a basic migration -- including user checkin mapping and comment stuff -- working with the free version.

Was it a recent change to remove this functionality from the free version, while it worked fine previously?

Comment: Hi Davis, please refer the answer in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291836/opshub-migrations-dont-seem-to-be-running-correctly-anymore/34305615#34305615. And yes, since this change is recent, the documents refer to the older tool features. We're working to update them.