# OpsHub Migrations don't seem to be running correctly anymore

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

A month or so ago I did a test migration of a few on-prem TFS projects to Visual Studio online. For the most part everything worked. Changesets were migrated over showing the same check-in user as on prem with a comment showing the original checkin date, user and changeset id. Same with workitems, I'd review the history and I'd see entries like "User1 (via MyUserACcount)".

Yesterday when I tried another migration I don't see any of the above. All the changesets show as my account with no migration details in the comments and the WorkItems only show me in the history.

Has the recent updates to VSO broken something?

Comment: OpsHub + Visual Studio Team Services still works, the migration includes history of version control changesets, work items, test cases, and test results. Are you using OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility from https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2 ?

Comment: Their newest update crippled these features in the free version, seems like that was the only real change.  It kind of looks bad for MS that a lot of their blogs and guides refer to this free tool they partnered to build which has now gone unfree, but that's just how it is I guess.

Comment: I totally agree. I found the utility from a migration page on MSDN. My path to VSTS is now blocked by having to pay multiple thousands of dollars to Opshub for use of their commercial utility. We are now re-evaluating whether we want to move at all.

Answer (score 0):

The OpsHub Migration Utility has been recently revamped. From the v2.0 the tool is been released under two variants.

1. Free Utility
2. Commercial Utility

Some features are not longer a part of the free version of the utility. A complete list of the differences between the two variants can be referred to from the [Gallery Page](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2) under the Section **2.3.3 Comparison between Free and Commercial Utility**

The feature that you are referring to, is impersonation, which is not longer supported in the Free Utility.

Comment: We did a few test migrations with a lot of success back in September. These changes are major and essentially render the free utility useless. I feel like I'm being held hostage now.