# OpsHub migration utility - Changeset check-In date

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I have seen that migrated changesets with the free migration utility (2.0) no longer migrates the actual user who made those CheckIns

My question is:

¿ What about the changeset check-In date ?

I have read is a Know limitation ( from https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2 ):

Point 6:

> Version Control Known Limitations
>
> 1. If Branch/Move across project has been done in your on-premises TFS and only some of those projects are selected for migration. Then the
>      utility will convert Branch/Rename (Move) -> to -> Add change type.
> 2. Branching of a folder as a new project is not supported by the utility. Since in the VSO the $/ProjectName folder already exists.
> 3. Migration of data in a project where tf destroy was performed with /keephistory parameter is not supported in the utility, since the data
>      in question is no longer present in TFS.
> 4. Labels created at Collection Level scope will not be migrated.
> 5. Migration of check-in notes, check-in policies is not supported.
> 6. The Check-in Date of a change set(s) will not be retained in VSO. Instead the current time value will be set by default.

As these limitations are below :

> 2.3.2 Functionalities Supported (Commercial Utility)

Does it means that The Check-In Date cannot be migrated with free even commercial Version ? 
Is there any workaround to migrate that check-in date? Or is not possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Original changeset check-In date will not be retained in VSO in any of the free or commercial Version of migration utility. But in the commercial version you will get the check-in comment with each change-set in VSO having original check-in information like - check-in by and check-in date.

Answer (score 0):

Original check-in information migration is no longer supported by free version now. You need to use commercial Version to get the original check-in date and user information migrated. Refer to this question for details: [OpsHub Migrations don't seem to be running correctly anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291836/opshub-migrations-dont-seem-to-be-running-correctly-anymore)